# Plone TinyMCE - creating custom CSS

Tags: css, tinymce, plone

I'm still in newbie mode. Reading Page 213 of "A users guide for Plone 4" in particular Choose the CSS used in WYSIWYG Editor area. Does anyone know of a tutorial / howto for this option of the TinyMCE Settings Setup, as I am still looking to add a lineswidget by creating a Custom CSS amongst other widgets within the editable area. TIA

Comment: This question is not entirely clear.  Are you trying to make custom CSS available in the styles dropdown in TinyMCE, or do something more complex?

Comment: Hi Jon, The text area that comes standard with Plone strips out list box to straight data when I try it with my limited HTML. (I am not a programmer) I would like to add a list box that would include 40plus items to choose a hyperlink to and then go back to main page or move to a new and future page. I am a consultant using open ended questions to drill to the solution and I believe that Plone can do this. It's me just trying to implement the widget easily without being a programmer. TIA

Comment: so you want to be able to have a list box inside your tinymce editor? (this is possible and can be configured)

Comment: Hi Thariama - Yes please, do you have a handy tutorial / how to as I am NOT a programmer - BUT learning by experience. I am the only user of Plone for 800km that I know of. I would like to include both a descriptive text and a list box on the same TinyMCE page.

Comment: You want an additional "Plugin" inside the TinyMCE toolbar?

Comment: Hi Maulwurfn - Looking for anything that gives me the opportunity to include concurrently both text and Listbox or similar - TIA

Comment: Just looking for all options ... now trying http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.CustomOverrides and  http://plone.org/documentation/kb/create-a-different-look-and-feel-for-different-sections-of-your-web-site-without-creating-new-skins

Comment: Is there any easy way to understand how to add widgets to data input via TinyMCE, as previously said I am an end user and I'm looking for a nerd's how to. TIA

Comment: Still doing my reading - does anybody have experience with ui.css contained within /portal_skins/tinymce/themes/advanced/skins/plone/ui.css - contains listbox - any how-to documentation on how to implement? Have been able to add to Custom but still no luck.